# Integrating a periodic absolute value function with exponential

Tags: integration, absolute-value, periodic-functions

I've been trying to answer this question and provide a closed form analytical solution.

The equation
$$
 f(t) = e{^{\sigma t}}cos(\omega t)
$$

$$
 F(t)=  \int_{0}^{t} |f(\tau)|d\tau 
$$

find F(t) any value of t given that
$$
\sigma <0 , \omega>0
$$

I've been trying a few ways to solve this, firstly by plotting the graph, which should look something similar to this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrHH9.png)

Based on this I broke down the integral into interval where
$$
\ |f(\tau)| 
$$
is positive and negative
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2} e{^{\sigma t}}cos(\omega t) - \int_{\pi/2}^{3\pi/2} e{^{\sigma t}}cos(\omega t) + \int_{3\pi/2}^{5\pi/2} e{^{\sigma t}}cos(\omega t) - \int_{5\pi/2}^{7\pi/2} e{^{\sigma t}}cos(\omega t)... $$

$$
\int e{^{\sigma t}}cos(\omega t) dt  = 
$$
$$
\ e{^{\sigma t}}(\sigma cos(\omega t) +\omega sin(\omega t)/ (\sigma ^2 + \omega ^2) 
$$

I'm really lost I think my approach makes sense,  but I don't know how to generalize for all values of t

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The big issue is that your period is $\frac {2 \pi} \omega$,  so you need to divide that up into quarters, not $0$ to $2\pi$.  And of course, not knowing the value of $\omega$ will mess things up.  My first suggestion is to try the "simplest case",  $\sigma =-1, \omega=1$ and try to solve that, then figure out how changing the parameters change things

Comment: You can use Euler's formula for the cosine function. This makes the integrations fairly easy to do, and you may be able to sum contributions from different intervals.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(\tau)=e^{\sigma\tau}\cos(\omega\tau)$$
lets focus on the periodicity of $\cos(\omega\tau)$ since $e^{\sigma\tau}>0\forall\sigma,\tau\in\mathbb{R}$. We know that:
$$|\cos(\omega\tau)|=\begin{cases}\cos(\omega\tau)&0<\omega\tau<\pi/2&\Rightarrow0<\tau<\pi/2\omega\\-\cos(\omega\tau)&\pi/2<\omega\tau<3\pi/2&\Rightarrow\pi/2\omega<\tau<3\pi/2\omega\\\cos(\omega\tau)&3\pi/2<\omega\tau<2\pi&\Rightarrow3\pi/2\omega<\tau<2\pi/\omega\end{cases}$$
so if we look at the simplest case, $t=2\pi$ we would have:
$$\int_0^{2\pi}|f(\tau)|d\tau=\int_0^{\pi/2\omega}\exp(\sigma\tau)\cos(\omega\tau)d\tau-\int_{\pi/2\omega}^{3\pi/2\omega}\exp(\sigma\tau)\cos(\omega\tau)d\tau+\int_{3\pi/2\omega}^{2\pi/\omega}\exp(\sigma\tau)\cos(\omega\tau)d\tau$$